# RAILS 3: How can I reload a partial?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, partial-views

I have a principal view. Inside it I have a button which render a partial with this JS code:

```
$('#add_more_lines_btn').click(function () {
    $("#trees_details").append("<%= escape_javascript( render "/green_trees/tree_details") %>");
});
```

The partial has multiple form elements which must have differents ids. The best idea I thought was calculate current time in milliseconds and append this to my ids:

```
 <% time_now = (Time.now.to_f*1000.0).to_i.to_s %>
```

The problem...

Each time when I click the button.. a partial displays correctly behind the first...but all form elements have the same id...so Rails, always, is painting the same partial and not calculate the time.

Why rails not loading a new partial (not the same each time)? Is possible do that without a call to controller?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your time trick is similar to what Ryan Bates did in his rails cast: http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised

I use the exact same technique as you do but you must ensure that your click handler does a search and replace to create a unique id (using client side time generation instead of server side)